# Why was this very relevant link moderated?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

[GNOME Screenshot area selection causing freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227402/gnome-screenshot-area-selection-causing-freezes)

I have this problem and needed the answer contained in the post and responses. I don't really care where it was posted, it was a good post, and if it offended someone it should have been moved rather than suppressed.  If not for Google's cache I would still be looking for this solution.

Answer (score 8):

The question was closed due to the original author answered:

> At some point in the last week or so, an update for something seems to have fixed this issue.

The close-reason was:

> This describes a problem that can't be reproduced, **that seemingly went away on its own** or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.

If you have the same or similar issue and still have it with all recent updates, you should open a new question explaining your problem.

Comment: This covers the closure, but I think this question is asking why the post was deleted

Answer (score 3):

I have undeleted the post since it was useful to you. The closure seems correct to me, but both the question, the self-answer and [the answer with the workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/1234430/527764) seem to at least have information that may help other users.